# Getting Doctrine associaton mappings

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a call that looks like the following:

```
$foo = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Bar')->find($id);
```

I would like to be able to loop over all of the column/value pairs that get returned into $foo. I have found that in most cases the following call gets me the information I want:

```
public function getEntityColumnValues($entity, $em){
  $cols = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity))->getColumnNames();
  $values = array();
  foreach($cols as $col){
    $getter = 'get' . $this->underscoreToCamelCase($col, true);
    $values[$col] = $entity->$getter();
  }
  return $values;
}
```

Sometimes, however, the entity contains some information that only exists as doctrine association mappings. That info ends out not being set in $values. Is there a way to loop over the values that get set in $foo without getting the class metadata via the getEntityColumnValues() function I have? Maybe there is a way I can enhance my function to get those mappings? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right way. `$em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity))` provides you the ClassMetadata with all the getters (eg. `getAssociationMappings`)you may need. Simply take a [look at them](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/php-mapping.html#field-association-getters) and feel free to experience.